# How to disable OPcache in Symfony to workaround in-lining bug (Cannot declare class Acme, because the name is already in use)?

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, opcache, preloading

I am using PHP 7.4, Laravel, and the most recent version of Symfony.

I have a webapp template running on Nginx, but it can't load routes due to a bug existing in Symfony since 2017 that leads to the error:

> Cannot declare class Acme, because the name is already in use

This comes up when troubleshooting 404 Not Found by running `php artisan route:list`. I have also tried clearing all caches, dump autoload, etc. I read the following resources, which are related but have not yet led to a solution for me:

- https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/25484
- https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/25334
- https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/20532
- https://github.com/symfony/demo/issues/411
- https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/25363
- https://symfony.com/doc/current/performance.html
- https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-4-preloading-symfony-applications-in-php-7-4

One of the developers suggested that this is due to a "conflict of inlining strategies" and offered the suggestion of not using `opcache`.

The only instructions I've found for disabling it seem to involve `.ini` files that are not used in my combination of software (Debian, Nginx, Laravel, PHP 7.4, artisan, composer - all at their most recent stable versions).

How can I disable it or otherwise resolve the quasi-conflict of "Cannot declare class Acme..."?

Comment: Welcome to SO ... where is it saying this error is coming from?

Comment: @lagbox The error does not specify any source - just `[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]` - and indeed there's no extra class declaration in any of the template code. It's just some false extra declaration created by the tools Symfony uses to pre-load code which are in conflict. So that's why I want to disable all unnecessary pre-loading.

Comment: Did you declare a `class Acme` yourself at all? Did the application work before? Also, did you do any major version upgrade beyond the default generated Laravel application.

Comment: If that is a bug since 2017, you should share a reproducer and report it. The linked issues are all closed as either fixed or not reproducable. If you ask for more help here, you should also share code such that others can reproduce your problem